# How to fix ImportError: No module named urls

Tags: django

i have installed django 1.10. And then ckeditor 5.0.3
When done with config i got an error "ImportError: No module named urls"
There is config settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'ckeditor',
]
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'upload/'
```

There is urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
```

There is urls.py of ckeditor_uploader:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import django
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

from . import views

if django.VERSION >= (1, 8):
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/', 
staff_member_required(views.upload),
name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^browse/', never_cache(staff_member_required(views.browse)), 
name='ckeditor_browse'),
]
else:
from django.conf.urls import patterns
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^upload/', staff_member_required(views.upload),
name='ckeditor_upload'),
    url(r'^browse/', never_cache(staff_member_required(views.browse)),
name='ckeditor_browse'),
)
```

Please any help!

WSGI_APPLICATION:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blago.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: just comment #(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')), helps......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the documentation](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor)

> **NOTICE: django-ckeditor 5 has backward incompatible code moves against 4.5.1.**
>
> File upload support have been moved to ckeditor_uploader. The urls are in ckeditor_uploader.urls while for file uploading widget you have to use RichTextUploadingField instead of RichTextField.

..

> Add `ckeditor_uploader` to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.

...

> Add CKEditor URL include to your project's urls.py file:
>
> ```
> (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Get another error: ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern ('^ckeditor/', (<module 'ckeditor_uploader.urls' from '/root/djangoenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ckeditor_uploader/urls.pyc'>, None, None)) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
        HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.

Comment: so trying url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')), work for me. Is it normal?